# Git show a bunch of files in my repo as deleted, but they are not

Tags: git

Very strange, suddently, git show most of the files in my repo as removed. `ls` shows them, `tree` shows them, I can open them.

I try to copy the repository to another folder, git status shows the same...

Any idea how this can happen, and how to solve this ?

EDIT: I managed to solve temporary this by copying only the `.git` folder to another directory, `git status` this repo, and then copying again all files to the new folder. Then after a while, it reshows the files as deleted...

EDIT2: To solve this, while keeping a copy of all my files, I hard rest to head, and then recopy the backuped files to the repo. Now everything is fine.

EDIT3 (more infos):
I'm keeping a copy of the broken repo folder in case. I let the question open because I'm still wondering how this can happen!

```
>> cat $(find . -name .gitignore)
git
*.pyc
*.lprof
*.cprof
profile.sh
/doc/
/.idea/
__pycache__
/tmp/
```

(sorry, in french, I translated as I can). Lots of files, just showing some examples

```
 >> git status
 Sur la branche master (on the branch master)
...
Modifications qui seront validées : (modification that will be validated)
  (utilisez "git reset HEAD <fichier>..." pour désindexer)
    (supprimé = deleted)
    supprimé :        GUI/MainWindows.py
    supprimé :        GUI/PathParameters.py
    supprimé :        GUI/parameter_utils.py
    supprimé :        GUI/ui/ui_DefaultPathDialog.py
    supprimé :        GUI/ui/ui_mainGUI.py
    supprimé :        examples/__init__.py
    supprimé :        externals/__init__.py
    supprimé :        main.py
    supprimé :        tools/searchUtils.py
    supprimé :        tools/spatial.py
    supprimé :        tools/utils.py
    supprimé :        tools/yaml.py
    ....

Modifications qui ne seront pas validées : (modification that won't' be validated)
  (utilisez "git add <fichier>..." pour mettre à jour ce qui sera validé)
  (utilisez "git checkout -- <fichier>..." pour annuler les modifications dans la copie de travail)
    (modifié = modified)
    modifié :         GUI/ui/ui_mainGUI.ui
    modifié :         requirements.txt

Fichiers non suivis: (files not followed)
  (utilisez "git add <fichier>..." pour inclure dans ce qui sera validé)

    GUI/MainWindows.py
    GUI/base/
    GUI/parameter_utils.py
    GUI/ui/ui_DefaultPathDialog.py
    GUI/ui/ui_mainGUI.py
    examples/
    externals/
    main.py
    tools/
```

`git diff --cached` shows a buch of the following, with the source code in red. It is very long, I wont put the source here. If you wan't more details, just ask !

```
>>git diff --cached

diff --git a/GUI/MainWindows.py b/GUI/MainWindows.py
deleted file mode 100644
index c9ef7ac..0000000
--- a/GUI/MainWindows.py
+++ /dev/null
```

as I explained, `ls` shows all the files listed as deleted above

Comment: Hard to say without a console transcript, but maybe you had a totally different Index state than exp3cted.

Comment: If you need give the output of some command, just ask! Just don't know what to show... Here, just typing `git status`, shows lots of file tagged as removed, but `ls` show the file, and I can open them

Comment: `git status` and `git diff --Index` and `cat $(find . -name .gitignore)` and a `ls` for starters. Or are u using git on Windows with some caching services?

Comment: There is also a `git update-Index —really-refresh`, maybe that will help (best to run it on a copy)

Comment: my git version is `git version 2.19.1`, `git diff --Index ` shows `error: option invalide : --Index`

Comment: Sorry it’s —Cache

Comment: I'm on linux, and I use smartgit. Smartgit shows the same as git, and closed, shows the same behaviour. Also I did restart, without any change

Comment: @eckes: It's lowercase, and ends with `d`: `git diff --cached` (or `git diff --staged`, which is a synonym), but that's not the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changes that are "to be committed" are those stored in the *index* (aka *staging area* aka *cache*).  Git makes new commits *from* whatever is in the index *right now*, so a good description of the index is that it is *what you are proposing to commit*.

If you copied the repository, but did not copy the index (or copied it in some way that did not retain all of it), that would explain the problem.  The index is neither the repository itself, nor the work-tree.  Instead, the index sits *between* the repository and the work-tree.  So the files can be there, in the work-tree, in fine order, but be missing from the index, and Git will tell you that a removal will be committed if you commit now.

You can tell Git to re-fill the index *from* the current commit, using `git reset --mixed`.  Or, you can write specified (or all) work-tree files using `git add`.  That is:

- `git reset --mixed`: copy (all files) from `HEAD` to index
- `git add file`: copy (the one specified *`file`*) from work-tree to index

If you view the index as being between the `HEAD` commit and the work-tree, this all makes more sense:

```
   HEAD           index         work-tree
----------      ----------      ----------
README.txt      README.txt      README.txt
file.ext        file.ext        file.ext
main.py         main.py         main.py
```

- The `HEAD` copy of each file is read-only: no commit can ever be changed, and it's a committed copy.  These files are compressed—maybe highly compressed—and in a special, Git-only format.
- The index copy of each file is Git-only, like the `HEAD` copy, except that it's read/write: it has been *unfrozen*.  The *next* commit will use the index copy, by freezing it (and once all the files are frozen and the commit is done, that index copy *becomes* the `HEAD` copy because `HEAD` changes to the new commit).
- The work-tree copy of each file is a normal file, in its normal form.  Git doesn't *use* it to make commits.  Git doesn't care very much *about* it, really; Git just provides it for *you* to use, work with, and maybe change if you like.

Once you've *changed* a file, you use `git add` to copy it back into the index, overwriting the old index copy.  The `add` process compresses and Git-ifies the file, so that it's ready to be committed.

The `git commit` command takes whatever's in the index *right now* and freezes that into a new commit.  The new commit becomes the `HEAD` commit.

When you first run `git checkout branch`, Git fills in the index and work-tree from the tip commit of *`branch`*.  That commit becomes the `HEAD` commit, and the `HEAD` and index match.  When you make a *new* commit, that new commit becomes the tip of the current branch, and the `HEAD` and index match.  Note how the work-tree was merely an *output* of the initial checkout, not an *input* of the new commit.  (It was, or rather some files in it were, put into to the *index* if you `git add`-ed some or all files.)

Normally you would remove files from the index using `git rm`:

- `git rm file` removes *`file`* from *both* the index *and* the work-tree; or
- `git rm file` removes *`file`* from the index, but leaves it alone in the work-tree.

Either way, after removing, say, `file.ext` from the index, you still have it in `HEAD`, so you have one of these two results:

```
   HEAD           index         work-tree
----------      ----------      ----------
README.txt      README.txt      README.txt
file.ext                        file.ext
main.py         main.py         main.py
```

or:

```
   HEAD           index         work-tree
----------      ----------      ----------
README.txt      README.txt      README.txt
file.ext
main.py         main.py         main.py
```

Looking in the work-tree won't tell you that the file's gone from the *index*, it will only tell you whether the file is gone from the *work-tree*.  But `git status` will tell you, because `git status` runs *two* `git diff`s:

- First, `git status` compares the `HEAD` commit to the index.  Whatever's different, Git tells you is a "change to be committed" ("qui seront validées", I guess).  Whatever's the *same*, Git says nothing about.
- Then, `git status` compares the index to the work-tree.  Whatever's different, Git tells you is a change that is not—at least, not yet—slated to be committed.  You could `git add` the updated file into the index, of course; after that, the first comparison, `HEAD` vs index, will show something different.
- A file that is not in the index, but is in the work-tree, is said to be *untracked* ("non suivis").  This is true even if the file is in the `HEAD` commit.  (Note, however, that you can suppress this complaint about untracked files by listing the file, or a pattern for it, in `.gitignore`.)

#### Conclusion: the files are in `HEAD` and the work-tree but not in the index

The output you showed is just what one should expect for this case.  The file is in `HEAD` but not in the index: it will be missing from the *next* commit, unless you put it back into the index.  And the file is not in the index, but is in the work-tree: it is untracked.

Comment: Thanks! That indeed fixed the broken repo. Do you have an idea how the files can be deleted from the index suddently ?

Comment: Under normal conditions, only `git rm --cached` would remove a file from the index while leaving it in the work-tree. If you set up a VM with a shared folder, or try to run Git over Dropbox or similar sharing systems, though, these *not*-normal conditions can cause Git data to become corrupted (including the repository itself). So it's a good idea to keep Git repositories purely local.

Comment: My git is purely local. Haven't run anything like `git rm --cached` myself, but maybe smartgit did corrupt the repo